# mysql count not working with join and where clause

Tags: mysql

If I am using this query:

```
SELECT clinic.id
FROM clinic 
JOIN dentist ON dentist.id = clinic.dentist_id 
JOIN user ON user.id = dentist.user_id 
WHERE user.status = 'Active'
AND clinic.status = 'Approved'
AND user.role_id = 2
GROUP BY clinic.id;
```

So it gives me all rows like

```
32
35
36
42
44
47
50
```

Bug If I am going to get total count of results so I apply query :

```
SELECT count(clinic.id) AS cnt
FROM clinic 
JOIN dentist ON dentist.id = clinic.dentist_id 
JOIN user ON user.id = dentist.user_id 
WHERE user.status = 'Active'
AND clinic.status = 'Approved'
AND user.role_id = 2
GROUP BY clinic.id;
```

I just applied count() to id, and it returns

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

It does not returns 7, I want result as 7.
Can anybody guide please.

Comment: you are retrieving the count per group there. try `select count(*) from (YOUR FIRST QUERY) q`

Comment: Just remove `GROUP BY`...

Comment: not necessarily. he may be using `group by` as a substitute for `distinct`

Comment: Ohk, eventually count is not working properly here just because of group by. Then I need to manage with this any other way.. !! Thanks to all for help :)

Comment: @ArvindKushwaha there are several answers here to your question, do any of them resolve it for you?

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices that I can see.  Since you are grouping, you are getting the count per group, which is expected behaviour. To get the total count, you either need to remove the `group by` and do this:

```
SELECT count(distinct clinic.id)
FROM clinic 
  JOIN dentist ON dentist.id = clinic.dentist_id 
  JOIN user ON user.id = dentist.user_id 
WHERE user.status = 'Active' 
 AND clinic.status = 'Approved' 
 AND user.role_id = 2
```

Or simply use your first query as a subquery in a new query, like this:

```
select count(*) from (
  SELECT clinic.id
  FROM clinic 
    JOIN dentist ON dentist.id = clinic.dentist_id 
    JOIN user ON user.id = dentist.user_id 
  WHERE user.status = 'Active' 
    AND clinic.status = 'Approved' 
    AND user.role_id = 2  
  GROUP BY clinic.id) q
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT count(clinic.id) AS cnt
FROM 
clinic 
JOIN dentist ON dentist.id = clinic.dentist_id 
JOIN user ON user.id = dentist.user_id 
WHERE user.status = 'Active' AND clinic.status = 'Approved' AND user.role_id = 2
```

Remove the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: if count is already only returning `1`, a distinct count isnt going to return any less.

Answer (score 0):

**DO NOT USE GROUP BY** or try this

```
SELECT clinicID,SUM(case when clinic !=null then 1 ELSE NULL END).id AS cnt
FROM clinic 
JOIN dentist ON dentist.id = clinic.dentist_id 
JOIN user ON user.id = dentist.user_id 
WHERE user.status = 'Active'
AND clinic.status = 'Approved'
AND user.role_id = 2
GROUP BY clinic.id;
```

Comment: how does that return the single number `7`, which is what was asked for? and how the hell did it get upvoted to 3?